# Web scraping - Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

How can I extract the entire content within "td"?

```
<td>
    Hand-painted by trained monkeys, these exquisite dolls are priceless! And by "priceless," we mean "extremely expensive"! 
    <span class="excitingNote">8 entire dolls per set! Octuple the presents!</span>
</td>
```

I tried this:

```
desc = data.xpath("//td/text()") 
print desc
```

But, it returns the first sentence only:

```
Hand-painted by trained monkeys, these exquisite dolls are priceless! And by "priceless," we mean "extremely expensive"!
```

I would like to have the output in the following format:

```
Hand-painted by trained monkeys, these exquisite dolls are priceless! And by "priceless," we mean "extremely expensive"! 8 entire dolls per set! Octuple the presents!
```

I also tried:

```
desc = data.xpath("//td//text()") 
    print desc
```

The output looks like this:

```
Hand-painted by trained monkeys, these exquisite dolls are priceless! And by "priceless," we mean "extremely expensive"! 
8 entire dolls per set! Octuple the presents!
```

I prefer the following:

```
Hand-painted by trained monkeys, these exquisite dolls are priceless! And by "priceless," we mean "extremely expensive"! 8 entire dolls per set! Octuple the presents!
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `//td//text()`?

Comment: please see my revised question.

Comment: `desc.replace("\n"," ")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked.

```
desc = data.xpath("//td") 
    print desc.text_content()
```